# Lucene: Escaping keywords for Surround QueryParser

Tags: lucene, surround

I'm using Lucene Contrib's [SurroundQueryParser](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SurroundQueryParser), and I've hit an issue with escaping keywords. Unlike Lucene's regular QueryParser, Surround seems to recognize even lower case and/or/not as keywords, and not only the uppercase version, which causes some queries to fail. Do you know a way to escape the keywords?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like regular quotes ("not") does the trick.